# Construct an explicit isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}]/(7)$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]/(7)$, where $(7)$ denotes that ideal generated by 7.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

Construct an explicit isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}]/(7)$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]/(7)$, where $(7)$ denotes that ideal generated by 7.

My idea is: We know that in the ring homomorphism identity map to identity, i.e $\phi(1)=1$, so fix $\phi(n)=n$. We want to construct isomorphism between these two rings; and let $x+y\sqrt{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}]/(7)$, and $\phi$ is a morphism then,

$\phi(x+y\sqrt{-1})=\phi(x)+\phi (y\sqrt{-1})=\phi(x)+\phi (y)\phi(\sqrt{-1})$.

If we define $\phi(\sqrt{-1})=\sqrt{-2}$, then it make isomorphism.

Is this idea correct to think this question? Anyone please suggest me some direction to solve this question?

Comment: Your map $\phi$ is not a ring homomorphism since $\phi(\sqrt{-1} \cdot \sqrt{-1}) \neq \phi(\sqrt{-1}) \cdot \phi(\sqrt{-1})$.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $3^2\equiv 2 \mod 7$.  Thus define $$\phi\colon \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]/(7)\to \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-1}]/(7) $$ by $\phi(\sqrt{-2})=3\sqrt{-1}$ and extend as you described.

Then $\phi(\sqrt{-2}\sqrt{-2})=-2$ and $\phi(\sqrt{-2})\phi\sqrt{-2})=-3^2=-2$, so we have a homomorphism.

The homomorphism is surjective as $\phi(5\sqrt{-2})=15\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{-1}$.  Any surjective map between finite sets is a bijection, so we have an isomorphism.

Comment: Perhaps more useful than the answer is how to come up with it.  When you are looking for an isomorphism, you are looking for elements on either side that behave the same.  Ordinarily $\sqrt{-2}$ looks nothing like something in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}]$.  This is because $\sqrt{2}$ is not an integer.  However because we are working modulo 7 here,   we just need to look for something that thinks it is $\sqrt{2}$ modulo 7.

Comment: can you explain why $\phi(\sqrt{-2}\sqrt{-2})=-2$?

Comment: @User124356 Yes: $\sqrt{-2}\sqrt{-2}=-2$.  Then $\phi(-2)=-2$ as you said "fix $\phi(n)=n$".

Answer (score 0):

You need $\phi(\sqrt{-1})^2=-1\in\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]/(7)$. So $\phi(\sqrt{-1})=a+b\sqrt{-2}$
where
$$a^2-2b^2+2ab\sqrt{-2}=-1\in\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]/(7),$$
that is $a^2-2b^2\equiv-1\pmod7$ and $2ab\equiv0\pmod 7$.

So either $a\equiv0$ or $b\equiv0\pmod7$, but we cannot have $b\equiv0\pmod7$
(why?) so $a\equiv0\pmod7$ and $-2b^2\equiv-1\pmod 7$. What are the solutions
to this congruence?